# Datasource not returned by sub class of parent class implementing UITableView, throwing exception

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I want to show some media of different categories (e.g. mostViewed, starred) in a UITableView. I created `APPParentViewController` which implements `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocol. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method in `APPParentViewController`, I return the appropriate cell which is filled with data coming from an array.

The array is actually instantiated in the `init` method in a sub class of `APPParentViewController`, which I exemplarily called `APPChildViewController`. There is one `APPChildViewController` for each media category. They just differ in the way the array is instantiated, the content of the array so to say.

I instantiate all `APPChildViewController` classes in another UIViewController (`[[APPChildViewController alloc] init]`) and then initially select one `APPChildViewController` to view (all happens in viewDidLoad method of that UIViewController). Working so far.

But when I want to show another `APPChildViewController` simply by removing the old view and adding the requested view (when the user requested it by pressing a button), I am getting the following exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:' ***
```

This is the code I am using (I removed everything which is not important in my opinion, so I hope it's still comprehensible):

APPParentViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface APPParentViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *media;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *tableView;
@end
```

APPParentViewController.m

```
#import "APPParentViewController.h"
#import "APPCell.h"

@interface APPParentViewController ()
@end

@implementation APPParentViewController
@synthesize media;
@synthesize tableView;

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
     self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
     [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

     self.tableView.delegate = self;
     self.tableView.dataSource = self;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
     return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     return [self.media count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     static NSString *CellTableIdentifier = @"CellTableIdentifier";
     static BOOL nibsRegistered = NO;
     if (!nibsRegistered) {
         UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"APPCell" bundle:nil];
         [self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:CellTableIdentifier];
         nibsRegistered = YES;
     }

     APPCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellTableIdentifier];
     NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
     NSDictionary *rowData = [self.media objectAtIndex:row];
     cell.title = [rowData objectForKey:@"Title"];
     return cell;
}
@end
```

APPChildViewController.h

```
#import "APPParentViewController.h"
@interface APPChildViewController : APPParentViewController
@end
```

APPChildViewController.m

```
#import "APPChildViewController.h"
#import "APPCell.h"

@interface APPChildViewController ()
@end

@implementation APPChildViewController

- (id)init
{
     self = [super init];
     if (self) {
          self.media = fill array...
     }
     return self;
}
```

It actually works when I copy the cellForRowAtIndexPath method implementation to all sub classes, but this is obviously not the way inheritance is intended to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make the switch, some cells will have a reference to the old child's media, and if that object is gone uh oh:

```
NSDictionary *rowData = [self.media objectAtIndex:row];
```

As soon so make the switch of dataSource, are you sending:

```
 [self.tableView reloadData];
```

I'm assuming (hoping!) that you have just the one nib owned by the parent...

Comment: Thanks, David! Where would you recommend to add this line: [self.tableView reloadData];? Yes, having just one nib owned by the parent.

Comment: Right - try that. What it will do is reload every cell, which will then use the current self.media array.

Comment: Yes, but where to add this line? I added it to different places in the parent, but it's not working...

Comment: Add it immediately after you switch the dataSource - in fact I often use a comma so it doesn't get separated: 'tableview.dataSource = foo, [tableView reloadData];'

Comment: As seen in my code examples above, I am setting the data source in the viewDidLoad method in the parent. When I add [tableView reloadData]; right after self.tableView.dataSource = self; it doesn't work.

Comment: In some ways that's good. its telling you that you have a problem early in the process. So add some log messages to your "self" dataSource methods, and see what you are returning (and whether you are getting messaged at all)